# Checking availability of domain names in PHP

Tags: php, dns

I wrote my own script for checking availability of domain names (in PHP) from a list of words contained in a text file but I get a high score of fake results.

I used checkdnsrr() function to check if there is a DNS record.

Is there a more efficient way to check availability of domain names ?

Thank you.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("list-words.txt", "r"); 

if ( $file)
{
     while ( ( $line = fgets( $file) ) !== false )
     { 
          $words[] .= cleanWord( trim( $line ) );
     }
     fclose( $file);
}

$nb = 5;
$ltd = '.com';
$list = '<ul>';
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $words); $i++ )
{ 
     if( strlen( $words[$i] ) == $nb_nb )
     { 
          if( !checkdnsrr( $words[$i].$ltd, 'ANY' ) )
          { 
              $list.= '<li>'.$words[$i].$ltd.'</li>';
          }
     }
}
$list.= '</ul>';
echo $list;
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463336/recommended-apis-for-checking-domain-availability

Comment: I would like to avoid WHOIS api..